# Box with color gradient in header (KomaScript) on page with new section

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, koma-script

I am trying to create a twosided document with KomaScript. I want to add an extra something to every page where a new section begins. I started with creating a new pagestyle according to [this post](https://texwelt.de/fragen/11777/wie-kann-ich-bei-koma-script-ein-individuelles-seitenlayout-einstellen). I tried to modify the example given there. So far, I have done this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3.8cm,right=2.2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[headsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Seite\nobreakspace\thepage}}
\automark[section]{section}
\ihead*{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[]{}
\ifoot[]{}

\newpairofpagestyles{highlights}{
    \chead{}
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
    \ohead*{\colorbox{blue!15}{%
            \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\color{white}%
                \hfill
                \pagemark}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Some text.
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{highlights}
\section{Section 2}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

This results in this style of header:

[image: Result so far]

I would like to achieve three things:

1. Create a **custom pagestyle** in the given MWE that I can activate on specific pages (where new sections begin) which contains the colorbar (which I specify in the following) and the pagenumber
2. Create the **colorbar with a color gradient behind thpage numberer in the header** (it would be nice if the colorbar optionally could also extend out of the header region in the inner or outer direction, depending on taste)
3. Change the **textcolor of the pagemark to be white**, so I have white text in front of the colorbar.

To visualize what I am after, I edited the important page of my MWE; **this is what I desire to achieve:**
[image]

I already tried to create a new pagestyle in the following way, which also was suggested in the above link. I don't have enough experience with `tikz` though to make it work:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,head,
contents={\hspace*{0cm}%
    \tikz{
        \fill[shade,left color=blue!0,right color=blue!20,right color=blue!70] (0,0)rectangle(20cm ,{1.4cm});
        \node[rotate=0,font=\bfseries] at({\textwidth-0.9cm},{0})
        {\ppagemark};
}}
]{highlights.bg}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{highlights}{highlights.bg}
```

Also, with this approach I don't even know how I would get the page number where I want.

Maybe someone of you has done this before or understands the matter deeply enough to be able to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what the desired result is supposed to be. But I would suggest to define a new layer for the header background:

```latex
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  hoffset=0pt,
  width=\paperwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putLL{\tikz{
    \ifodd \value{page}
      \fill[shade,left color=blue!0,right color=blue!70]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
    \else
      \fill[shade,left color=blue!70,right color=blue!0]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
    \fi
  }}
}
]{highlights.bg}
```

Then you can add this layer at the beginning of your new defined pagestyle:

```
\newpairofpagestyles{highlights}{
  \ohead{\pagemark}
  \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
  \addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{white}}
}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{highlights}{highlights.bg}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman, twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3.8cm,right=2.2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{tikz}% loads xcolor, graphicx etc.

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Seite\nobreakspace\thepage}}
\automark[section]{section}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\newpairofpagestyles{highlights}{
  \ohead{\pagemark}
  \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
  \addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{white}}
}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  hoffset=0pt,
  width=\paperwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putLL{\tikz{
    \ifodd \value{page}
      \fill[shade,left color=blue!0,right color=blue!70]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
    \else
      \fill[shade,left color=blue!70,right color=blue!0]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
    \fi
  }}
}
]{highlights.bg}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{highlights}{highlights.bg}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Some text.

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{highlights}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if every section in your document should start on a new odd page, then you can switch to class `scrreprt` with option `open=right`. So here is an additional suggestion assuming that pagestyle `highlights` uses the same layers as pagestyle `plain.scrheadings` and the new layer `highlight.bg`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman, twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterindent=false]{chapter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3.8cm,right=2.2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{tikz}% loads xcolor, graphicx etc.

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Seite\nobreakspace\thepage}}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,% not on even pages in two-sided documents
  head,
  hoffset=0pt,
  width=\paperwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putLL{\tikz{
    \fill[shade,left color=blue!0,right color=blue!70]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
  }}
}
]{highlights.bg}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{highlights}{highlights.bg}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{\AddLayersToPageStyle{highlights}{#1}}% <- add all plain.scrheadings layers to the new page style
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{highlights}{oninit=\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{white}}\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{highlights}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Some text.
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update** (regarding a comment below)

You can use options `addheight`, `addhoffset`, `addvoffset`, `addwidth`, `height`, `hoffset`, `voffset` and `width` to adjust the position and the size of the new defined layer with the background rule.

If you want to enlarge the header background rule vertically, you can use options `addvoffset` and `addheight` in the layer definition.

Example for the second MWE above:

```latex
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,% not on even pages in two-sided documents
  head,
  addvoffset=2mm,% moves the layer 2mm down
  addheight=4mm,% enlarges the height of the layer by 4mm
  hoffset=0pt,
  width=\paperwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putLL{\tikz{
    \fill[shade,left color=blue!0,right color=blue!70]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
  }}
}
]{highlights.bg}
```

[image]

If the background rule should reach from the inner text to the outer paper border, do not change `hoffset` and adjust the `width`:

```latex
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,% not on even pages in two-sided documents
  head,
  addvoffset=2mm,% moves the layer 2mm down
  addheight=4mm,% enlarges the height of the layer by 4mm
  %hoffset=0pt,% <- removed
  width=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin,% <- changed
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putLL{\tikz{
    \fill[shade,left color=blue!0,right color=blue!70]
      (0,0)rectangle(\the\layerwidth,\the\layerheight);
  }}
}
]{highlights.bg}
```

[image]

Note, that you need a second layer if the background should be used in a two-sided document on even pages too.

Comment: This is pretty much spot on what I tried to achieve. Kudos! Thank you  for taking the extra step explaining the even better second solution.

One small followup question: what would I have to change in the tikz definition of the rectangle to e.g. make it a little bid larger in the vertical direction (so that it is ranging further above and below the page number), so that it becomes even a little more noticeable? I don't really understand yet which part of the command defines from where to where it ranges and how wide and tall the rectangle is.

Comment: (or, for example, what would I do if I wanted  the bar to reach from the outside of the document to the inner side of the text (so not completely to the other side od the page)?)

Comment: @Pidrittel I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, you just create the layer with corresponding bounds and then fill it completely. Thank you very much for explaining! Now I can alter the rest on my own.